# Whats the difference between imitate and impersonate and mimic?

Tags: difference

do they mean the same ? Can they be used inter-changeably?

Comment: More details or examples are needed. Did you compare the dictionary definitions?

Answer (score 4):

*Imitate* means to do something in the same way as something or someone else.

*Mimic* means to copy someone's actions or other observable expressions.

There's not a big difference between those words.  *Mimic* may have more of a connotation of mindless copying of another individual, as though X is copying the outward look/actions of Y but not necessarily understanding why those actions are done.  If you describing someone copying someone else's mannerisms for entertainment, *mimic* is the better word.

A side note: *imitate* and *emulate* mean different things though some people confuse them.  Don't fall into this trap.

*Impersonate* means to pretend you are another person - the subject and object of *impersonate* is generally a person or person-like thing.  When you are *impersonating* you are trying to fool others into thinking you are the other person, this is not necessarily something you are doing when imitating or mimicking - though imitating/mimicking is certainly *involved in* impersonating.